# Update with join in SQL doesn't work on all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Table A

```
name | amount
a    | 100
b    | 200
C    | 300
```

And Table B like

```
name  | amount
a     | 50
b     | 50
C     | 100
a     | 200
```

I want to update Table A and my query is like this

```
UPDATE A 
   SET A.Amount += B.Amount
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.Name = A.Name
```

And I hope to see

```
a  | 350
```

but it returns

```
a | 150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate `b` first before joining.  I would recommend:

```
UPDATE A 
   SET A.Amount = A.Amount + B.Amount
FROM A JOIN
     (SELECT B.NAME, SUM(B.Amount) as Amount
      FROM B
      GROUP BY B.NAME
     ) B
     ON B.Name = A.Name;
```

In particularly, I strongly recommend this over the correlated subquery solution, because that solution updates every row.  This only updates the names in `B`.

The issue with your query is that multiple rows match the `JOIN` condition.  Only one is (arbitrarily) chosen for the `UPDATE`.  This is well-documented in the SQL Server documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
    update table_a
    set amount = y.amount
    from
        (
        select name, sum(amount) as amount
        from 
            (
                select name, amount
                from table_a
                union 
                select name, amount
                from table_b
            )z
        group by name
        )y
    where table_a.name = y.name
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to over-complicate it, assuming you need to update the entire table, just use a sub-query.

```
UPDATE A SET Amount += COALESCE((SELECT SUM(B.Amount) from B where B.[Name] = A.[NAME]),0);
```